# Terraform: how do you inspect sensitive data?

Tags: terraform, security

In a resource of type `aws_ecs_task_definition` my plan has an line that looks like this:

```
~ container_definitions    = (sensitive) # forces replacement
```

Now in principle this could be doing anything - deleting all my containers, spinning up bitcoin mining containers, etc.

Is there any way I can look at the data, both the old and the new?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your configuration or a provider marks an attribute as sensitive, Terraform will always hide that value in any output that's intended for human consumption.

The real values are available in machine-readable output though. This is primarily with the aim of integrating with external software, but if you need to then you can also inspect the machine-readable output directly yourself.

You can get a machine-readable (JSON) rendering of a plan like this:

```
terraform plan -out=tfplan
terraform show -json tfplan
```

If you intend to read it directly in the terminal then it can help to pipe it into [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), if you have that utility installed:

```
terraform show -json tfplan | jq
```